# How can I link an edit page to my detail profile page in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

So I am trying to link the template where I can edit a user_profile like this:

Edit

But is giving me this error:

NoReverseMatch at /user_profile/9/
Reverse for 'user_profile_update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'user_profile/(?P\d+)/edit/$']

But I can get access to the template like this without an error: /user_profile/(id)/edit

This is my view:

```
def user_profile_update(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(user_profile, id=id)
    form = user_profileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "first_name": instance.first_name,
        "instance": instance,
        "form":form,
         }
return render(request, "user_profile/user_profile_form.html", context)
```

This is my url:

```
url(r'^create/$', user_profile_create,name='create'),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', user_profile_detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$',user_profile_update, name='edit'),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', user_profile_delete),
```

And this is my model:

```
class user_profile(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
    address_1 = models.CharField(_("Address"), max_length=128)
    address_2 = models.CharField(_("Address 1"), max_length=128, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=64, default="pune")
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    pin_code = models.CharField(_("pin_code"), max_length=6, default="411028")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("user_profile:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]
```

I would be really glad if someone could help me!

Comment: this error:
NoReverseMatch at ************ Reverse for 'user_profile_update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'user_profile/(?P\d+)/edit/$']

Means:
-Django in order to load a template chek if all links exist if you use {% url 'some/url.html' somepram %}
-When django forms the html in server, it try to acces: /user_profile/(id)/edit  with this params :  '{u'id': ''}':
like if you try to acces: /user_profile/{u'id': ''}/edit

Ensure you are passing the correct id to the HTML

Answer (score 1):

You need separate views and URL-conf for editing and detail view. You only have `^user_profile/(?P\d+)/edit/$'` in your URL-conf, so you can only access the view from `user_profile/123/edit/`. So you need to add another URL `'^user_profile/(?P\d+)/$` to access from `user_profile/123/`.
The same with views, you need two separate ones for the simplest solution.